# symfony: question about url_for

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

how to add parameters in the url_for() function? I mean, I have this route:

```
category_set_representative_image:
  url:     /categoria-settare-immaggine-rappresentativa/:id
  param:   { module: category_new, action: setRepresentativeImage }
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: Category, type: object }
```

I want to generate the url through `url_for('category_set_representative_image', $category)`, but how to add besides the parameter ":id" (the id of the image that will be representative of the category)?

sf 1.4

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `url_for('category_set_representative_image', $category)` works indeed if you have only one parameter. If you want to add more parameters, you can use `url_for('category_set_representative_image', array('sf_subject' => $category, 'extra_param' => 'foo'))`.

So the `sf_subject` is the object that is used for the object routing. All other params will be tried to be matched in the URL itself, and if not found appended as a query string.

(For example, of you have a route with url `/categories/:id/params/:extra_param`, it will fill the :extra_param token, and your URL will look like `/categories/11/params/foo`, if it isn't defined in the routing, the url will look like `/categories/:id?extra_param=foo`.
In both cases you can get the value of the parameter in the action with `$request->getParameter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
url_for('category_set_representative_image?id=YOURIDHERE', $category);
```

Answer (score 0):

`url_for('@category_set_representative_image?id=YOURIDHERE', $category);`

for routes you will have to use the @ in front